# SQLalchemy issue recovering binary data from MSSQL Column

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

From the database

```
Id EndpointId  MacAddress  IsDefault   IsAuto
```

16  -2147483641 0x08002781A502  1   1
20  -2147483639 0x005056A54212  1   1

MacAddress column is BINARY(6) datatype

I'm using FreeTDS with Python and SQLAlchemy to get the data.

```
mymetadata = MetaData(engine_idf)

macadds = Table('EndpointsMacs',mymetadata,schema='dbo',autoload=True)

for row in macadds.select(macadds.c.IsDefault == 1).execute():
    print row
```

What I get back is.

(16, -2147483641, "\x08\x00'\x81\xa5\x02", True, True)

(20, -2147483639, '\x00PV\xa5B\x12', True, True)

I need to get the third value in the text equivalent so that I can work with the actual value of 08002781A502

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`binascii.hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) (or `binascii.h2a_hex`) to get hexadecimal representation:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify("\x08\x00'\x81\xa5\x02")
'08002781a502'
```

and `binascii.unhexlify` in case you want to get binary data representation: